# Laravel : Missing required parameters for route

Tags: php, forms, laravel, uri

I have the following route :

```
Route::post('new-password/{id}/{random}',['as'=>'postNewPassword','uses'=>'AbcController@postNewPassword']);
```

And I am using that route in form action and passing the required parameters like:

```
action="{{ route('postNewPassword',Request::segment(2),Request::segment(3))}}"
```

The Url is :

`http://localhost:8080/new-password/14/yxbH1sP4mdRngtCqQ9VS1KeksadOf5Piwc784HeQ`

I don't know what am I missing. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass all route paramters as the seconds parameter, so change code to:

```
route('postNewPassword', [Request::segment(2), Request::segment(3)])
```

Comment: Dang it, Thanks though